# Image stored on s3 Bucket not loading on physical device - React Native

Tags: amazon-s3, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

I'm working on an application in React Native that requires to display images from the network. These images are stored on an S3 bucket that I own.

When I try to display the images on my simulator everything goes perfectly. However when I test my code on TestFlight (same behavior on android) no image is displayed.

Here are the tracks I have already explored :

- The images I store have no extension. Is this a problem?
- My guess would be that the problem is due to an error in the HTTPS certificate? I've also tested it on Amazon Cloud Front and got the same result.

Do you have any idea what could cause this error and an idea for the solution.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: while sending image key to the aws you need to pass extension as well. else image wont show up. Im not sure about the second point you mentioned. but you need to mention extension as well while uploading image to AWS bucket.

Comment: The point is that it's working without file extension on Simulator but not on TestFlight, so i don't think the bug is linked to this..